# How to get started with the Alibaba Cloud Quantum Computing Service?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

According to [this press announcement](https://www.alibabacloud.com/press-room/alibaba-cloud-and-cas-launch-one-of-the-worlds-most) from March 1st 2018, the Alibaba Cloud offers access to an 11 qubit quantum computer via their cloud services. Quote:

> Alibaba Cloud, [...] and Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) [...] have launched the superconducting quantum computing cloud, featuring a quantum processor with 11 quantum bits (qubits) of power. [...]
>
> Users can now access the superconducting quantum computing cloud through Alibaba Cloud’s quantum computing cloud platform to efficiently run and test custom built quantum codes and download the results.

However, I have been unable to find any mention of this service anywhere else on their site than in the press announcement. No documentation. No mention in the "Products" overview. Nothing. Does anyone know, how to get started here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://quantumcomputer.ac.cn

They really need to get their act together and make sure it's on the first page of Google. I had to go way into uncharted territory to find this. (Like, not the first page of Google.)

Answer (score 2):

The website where you could access this 11-qubit quantum computer via a cloud service is not public yet. When it becomes public, the, of course, it will be posted here.

Comment: Website seems to be accessible right now: https://quantumcomputer.ac.cn/Login.html.